# ¿Cómo puedo adaptar mi ventana modal a celulares?

Tags: html, css, modal

Tengo una página que está adaptada para celulares con una medida de `800px`, pero si se reducen las dimensiones se observa que la ventana contacto y la ventana política de privacidad son las únicas que no se adaptan [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código:**

```css
* *, *::before, *::after{ box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    body {
 background: #000000;
 color: #000000;
} 
header, footer {
 background: #000000;
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 30%
 margin:20% auto;

}

header nav {
 background: #000000;
 overflow: hidden;
}
header nav ul {
 list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li {
 float:right;
}
 header nav ul li a {
  padding: 3% 6%;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;


 }
  header nav ul li a:hover {
   background: #55d737;
  }
 
.main {
  background: #000000;
  display: flex;
  padding: : 0%
  
} 


.main aside,
.main .article{
  padding: 2%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.main .iz{
  width: 15%;
}
.main .de {
 width: 15%
}
.iz{
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  order: 1;
}

.de{
  background: white;
  order: 3;
}

.article{
  order: 2;
  width: 70%;
  background: white;
}

article{
  background: white;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

footer {
background: #000;
color:#fff;
clear:both
padding:10% 0%;
text-align: center;
}

.centro {
 text-align: center;
}

a.open{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 0.5em;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 2% 2% 0% #000;
}

section.modalDialog{
 background-color: white;
 bottom: 0;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 position: fixed;
 display: none;
 z-index: 2;
}

section.modalDialog:target{
 display: block;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 60%;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 22%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 1%;
 top:2%;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 3%;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #000;
}

section.modal{
 background-color: #111;
 box-shadow: 0% 0% 10% #000;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 5% auto;
 padding: 5%;
 position: relative;
 width: 60%;
}

.diferencia {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.diferente{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
/** Posible Solución a la pregunta **/

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
 .main{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 }
 .main .iz {
 display:inline-block;
 width:95%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
 .main .de {
 display:inline-block;
 width:95%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
 .de p {
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:inline;
 }
 .iz p {
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:inline;
 }
 .article {
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
 article {
 margin:1% auto;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Bienvenidos</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="imagenes/ale2.jpg">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <header>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "VideoObject",
  "name": "enviar mensaje masivo outlook office ",
  "description": "las personas lo reciben como que si estuviera destinado solo a ellos y no como una cadena,  cada persona verá su propia dirección de correo en el mensaje y no la del resto de contactos",
  "thumbnailUrl": [
    "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1LhkxeHZm0A/hqdefault.jpg"
   ],
  "uploadDate": "2017-10-23T19:57:00",
  "duration": "PPT4M28S",
  "embedUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/1LhkxeHZm0A",
  "interactionCount": "67"
}
</script>
<div class="logotipo"><img src="imagenes/ale2.jpg" width="70" alt="logotipo"> </div>
<aside class="arriba">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
  </aside>

  <nav>
  <ul><li>
<div class="contenedor">
     <a href="#" class="open">INICIO</a>
  </div>
</li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal1" class="open"> ACERCA DE </a>
      <section id="openmodal1" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> acerca de</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Este sitio abarca tutoriales para dar soluciones destinadas a resolver dudas acerca de todo tipo de ideas útiles para el internauta</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal2" class="open">POLITICA DE PRIVACIDAD</a>
      <section id="openmodal2" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> politica de privacidad</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Esta permitido compartir todo el contenido de este sitio, más no está permitido copiar cual fiel copia, para usarlo en el desarrollo de otro sitio web, todo o parte del contenido de mi sitio web. En cualquier caso que se inserte cualquier parte del contenido en otro sitio web se deberá hacer referencia de que se está compartiendo el contenido y de forma notoria que dicho contenido es de mi autoria: Susana Alexadra Loor García y de que se extrajo de: <a href="https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com">https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/</a> Por lo tanto se establece que se respetará este sitio web como propiedad de la autora, y nadie se podrá adujudicar a su autoria todo del contenido de dicho sitio</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal3" class="open"> CONTACTO</a>
      <section id="openmodal3" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> CONTACTO</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Comunicate con nosotros a este correo susanaloorgarcia@gmail.com</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div> </li>
    <li>
       <div class="contenedor">
        <a target="_blank" class="open" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a>
       </div>
 </li>
  </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="main">
    <aside class="de">
    <h3></h3>
    <p><a href="paginas principales/acceso incognito.html">acceso a incognito desde el icono principal</a></p><br>
<p><a href="paginas principales/captura de pantalla.html"> capturar pantalla sin paint</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/clavewindows.html">conocer la clave de windows instalada en tu equipo</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/configmicrofono.html">configurar el microfono para que se escuche bien en audio/video</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/convertir ventana a pestaña.html">convertir ventana a pestaña y viceversa</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/cookies chrome.html">desactivar, activar cookies en chrome</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/cortar video.html">cortar video de youtube</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/direccion ip.html">conocer dns, direccion ip, gategay o puerta de enlace predeterminada y mascara de subred</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/enviar mensaje masivo.html">enviar mensaje masivo outlook office</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/excepciones avira.html">añadir excepciones a avira</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/google ncr.html">hacer busquedas globales y en cualquier idioma</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/grabadora.html">localizar los archivos de la grabadora de sonido</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/guardar sesión chrome.html">guardar sesion en chrome rapidamente</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/k de youtube.html">averigua que significa la k en youtube</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/ocultar video.html">ocultar informacion y partes de video</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/rejected git push heroku master.html">solucionar el error de rejected git push heroku master</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/traducir texto.html">traducir texto rapidamente</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/vista windows.html">gesto del mouse pack para cambio inesperado de aplicaciones en windows</a> </p><br>
  </aside>
  <aside class="iz">
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Compartir</a></div>
  </aside>
  <section class="article">
    <article>
      <h2>Tutoriales</h2><br>

        <p class="centro"><a href="paginas principales/rejected git push heroku master.html"><img src="imagenes/1.jpg" width="150" alt="solucion a rejeted git push heroku master" title="solucion a rejeted git push heroku master"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/enviar mensaje masivo.html"><img src="imagenes/2.jpg" width="150" alt="enviar mensaje masivo outlook office" title="enviar mensaje masivo outlook office"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/traducir texto.html"><img src="imagenes/3.jpg" width="150" alt="traducir texto rápidamente" title="traducir texto rápidamente"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/google ncr.html"><img src="imagenes/4.jpg" width="150" alt="hacer busquedas globales" title="hacer busquedas globales y en cualquier idioma google ncr"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/k de youtube.html"><img src="imagenes/6.jpg" width="150" alt="k de youtube" title="k de youtube"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/grabadora.html"><img src="imagenes/7.jpg" width="150" alt="localización de archivos de la grabadora de sonido" title="localización de archivos de la grabadora de sonido"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/clavewindows.html"><img src="imagenes/8.jpg" width="150" alt="Conocer la contraseña instalada de tu windows" title="conocer la contraseña instalada de tu windows"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/excepciones avira.html"><img src="imagenes/9.jpg" width="150" alt="añadir excepciones de avira" title="añadir excepciones de avira"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/acceso incognito.html"><img src="imagenes/10.jpg" width="150" alt="acceso directo a incognito desde el icono" title="acceso directo a incognito desde el icono google chrome"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/direccion ip.html"><img src="imagenes/11.jpg" width="150" alt="direccion ip dns etcetera" title="obtener dirección ip, gateway, dns, mascara de subred"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/vista windows.html"><img src="imagenes/12.jpg" width="150" alt="cambio de accdidenta de aplicaciones de windows 8" title="cambio de accdidenta de aplicaciones de windows 8"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/captura de pantalla.html"><img src="imagenes/13.jpg" width="150" alt="atajo para capturar pantalla sin paint" title="atajo para capturar pantalla sin paint"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/cookies chrome.html"><img src="imagenes/14.jpg" width="150" alt="desactivar cookies en chrome" title="desactivar cookies en chrome"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/configmicrofono.html"><img src="imagenes/15.jpg" width="150" alt="configurar microfono" title="configurar microfono"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/ocultar video.html"><img src="imagenes/16.jpg" width="150" alt="ocultar información de video" title="Tapar información de video"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/cortar video.html"><img src="imagenes/17.jpg" width="150" alt="cortar video de youtube" title="cortar video de youtube"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/guardar sesión chrome.html"><img src="imagenes/18.jpg" width="150" alt="guardar sesión e chrome rápidamente" title="guarda sesión en chrome rápidamente"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/convertir ventana a pestaña.html"><img src="imagenes/5.jpg" width="150" alt="convertir ventana a pestaña y vicecersa" title="convertir ventana a pestaña y vicecersa"></a></p>
    </article>
  </section>
  
  </section>
  <footer><p>Portoviejo-Manabí-Ecuador</p></footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias maneras, depende de como quieres que se vea.

Por ejemplo puedes agregar más espacio a ese modal específico, agregando una clase, por poner un ejemplo **modal-ancho** :

```
.modal-ancho{
  width: 90%;
}
```

Y así solo ese modal se vería más grande que los demás.

Lo otro es que solo se vea así en moviles, entonces:

```
@media (max-width: XXXpx){
  .modal-ancho{ 
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

Además si quieres que por ejemplo haya un scroll cuando la ventana llegue a un tope, entonces sería así.

```
  .modal-ancho{ 
    width: 90%; 
    max-height: 80vh; /*O el 80% de la altura de la ventana*/
    overflow: auto. 
  }
```

ya si quieres que se adapte diferente, tendrías que mostrarnos un ejemplo o una imagen de como quieres que se vea. Éxitos!

```css
/*Lo pongo acá arriba, porque ya es mucho código*/

section.modal.modal-ancho{
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 80vh; /*O lo que quieras o veas que se adpate mejor*/
  /*overflow: auto; u otra opción es que solo sea en la altura el scroll*/
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: none;
}


* *, *::before, *::after{ box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    body {
 background: #000000;
 color: #000000;
} 
header, footer {
 background: #000000;
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 30%
 margin:20% auto;

}

header nav {
 background: #000000;
 overflow: hidden;
}
header nav ul {
 list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li {
 float:right;
}
 header nav ul li a {
  padding: 3% 6%;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;


 }
  header nav ul li a:hover {
   background: #55d737;
  }
 
.main {
  background: #000000;
  display: flex;
  padding: : 0%
  
} 


.main aside,
.main .article{
  padding: 2%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.main .iz{
  width: 15%;
}
.main .de {
 width: 15%
}
.iz{
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  order: 1;
}

.de{
  background: white;
  order: 3;
}

.article{
  order: 2;
  width: 70%;
  background: white;
}

article{
  background: white;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

footer {
background: #000;
color:#fff;
clear:both
padding:10% 0%;
text-align: center;
}

.centro {
 text-align: center;
}

a.open{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 0.5em;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 2% 2% 0% #000;
}

section.modalDialog{
 background-color: white;
 bottom: 0;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 position: fixed;
 display: none;
 z-index: 2;
}

section.modalDialog:target{
 display: block;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 60%;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 22%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 1%;
 top:2%;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 3%;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #000;
}

section.modal{
 background-color: #111;
 box-shadow: 0% 0% 10% #000;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 5% auto;
 padding: 5%;
 position: relative;
 width: 60%;
}

.diferencia {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.diferente{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
/** Posible Solución a la pregunta **/

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
 .main{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 }
 .main .iz {
 display:inline-block;
 width:95%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
 .main .de {
 display:inline-block;
 width:95%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
 .de p {
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:inline;
 }
 .iz p {
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:inline;
 }
 .article {
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
 article {
 margin:1% auto;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Bienvenidos</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="imagenes/ale2.jpg">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <header>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "VideoObject",
  "name": "enviar mensaje masivo outlook office ",
  "description": "las personas lo reciben como que si estuviera destinado solo a ellos y no como una cadena,  cada persona verá su propia dirección de correo en el mensaje y no la del resto de contactos",
  "thumbnailUrl": [
    "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1LhkxeHZm0A/hqdefault.jpg"
   ],
  "uploadDate": "2017-10-23T19:57:00",
  "duration": "PPT4M28S",
  "embedUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/1LhkxeHZm0A",
  "interactionCount": "67"
}
</script>
<div class="logotipo"><img src="imagenes/ale2.jpg" width="70" alt="logotipo"> </div>
<aside class="arriba">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
  </aside>

  <nav>
  <ul><li>
<div class="contenedor">
     <a href="#" class="open">INICIO</a>
  </div>
</li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal1" class="open"> ACERCA DE </a>
      <section id="openmodal1" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> acerca de</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Este sitio abarca tutoriales para dar soluciones destinadas a resolver dudas acerca de todo tipo de ideas útiles para el internauta</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal2" class="open">POLITICA DE PRIVACIDAD</a>
      <section id="openmodal2" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal modal-ancho">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> politica de privacidad</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Esta permitido compartir todo el contenido de este sitio, más no está permitido copiar cual fiel copia, para usarlo en el desarrollo de otro sitio web, todo o parte del contenido de mi sitio web. En cualquier caso que se inserte cualquier parte del contenido en otro sitio web se deberá hacer referencia de que se está compartiendo el contenido y de forma notoria que dicho contenido es de mi autoria: Susana Alexadra Loor García y de que se extrajo de: <a href="https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com">https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/</a> Por lo tanto se establece que se respetará este sitio web como propiedad de la autora, y nadie se podrá adujudicar a su autoria todo del contenido de dicho sitio</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal3" class="open"> CONTACTO</a>
      <section id="openmodal3" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> CONTACTO</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Comunicate con nosotros a este correo susanaloorgarcia@gmail.com</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div> </li>
    <li>
       <div class="contenedor">
        <a target="_blank" class="open" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a>
       </div>
 </li>
  </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="main">
    <aside class="de">
    <h3></h3>
    <p><a href="paginas principales/acceso incognito.html">acceso a incognito desde el icono principal</a></p><br>
<p><a href="paginas principales/captura de pantalla.html"> capturar pantalla sin paint</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/clavewindows.html">conocer la clave de windows instalada en tu equipo</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/configmicrofono.html">configurar el microfono para que se escuche bien en audio/video</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/convertir ventana a pestaña.html">convertir ventana a pestaña y viceversa</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/cookies chrome.html">desactivar, activar cookies en chrome</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/cortar video.html">cortar video de youtube</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/direccion ip.html">conocer dns, direccion ip, gategay o puerta de enlace predeterminada y mascara de subred</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/enviar mensaje masivo.html">enviar mensaje masivo outlook office</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/excepciones avira.html">añadir excepciones a avira</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/google ncr.html">hacer busquedas globales y en cualquier idioma</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/grabadora.html">localizar los archivos de la grabadora de sonido</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/guardar sesión chrome.html">guardar sesion en chrome rapidamente</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/k de youtube.html">averigua que significa la k en youtube</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/ocultar video.html">ocultar informacion y partes de video</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/rejected git push heroku master.html">solucionar el error de rejected git push heroku master</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/traducir texto.html">traducir texto rapidamente</a></p><br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/vista windows.html">gesto del mouse pack para cambio inesperado de aplicaciones en windows</a> </p><br>
  </aside>
  <aside class="iz">
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Compartir</a></div>
  </aside>
  <section class="article">
    <article>
      <h2>Tutoriales</h2><br>

        <p class="centro"><a href="paginas principales/rejected git push heroku master.html"><img src="imagenes/1.jpg" width="150" alt="solucion a rejeted git push heroku master" title="solucion a rejeted git push heroku master"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/enviar mensaje masivo.html"><img src="imagenes/2.jpg" width="150" alt="enviar mensaje masivo outlook office" title="enviar mensaje masivo outlook office"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/traducir texto.html"><img src="imagenes/3.jpg" width="150" alt="traducir texto rápidamente" title="traducir texto rápidamente"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/google ncr.html"><img src="imagenes/4.jpg" width="150" alt="hacer busquedas globales" title="hacer busquedas globales y en cualquier idioma google ncr"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/k de youtube.html"><img src="imagenes/6.jpg" width="150" alt="k de youtube" title="k de youtube"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/grabadora.html"><img src="imagenes/7.jpg" width="150" alt="localización de archivos de la grabadora de sonido" title="localización de archivos de la grabadora de sonido"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/clavewindows.html"><img src="imagenes/8.jpg" width="150" alt="Conocer la contraseña instalada de tu windows" title="conocer la contraseña instalada de tu windows"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/excepciones avira.html"><img src="imagenes/9.jpg" width="150" alt="añadir excepciones de avira" title="añadir excepciones de avira"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/acceso incognito.html"><img src="imagenes/10.jpg" width="150" alt="acceso directo a incognito desde el icono" title="acceso directo a incognito desde el icono google chrome"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/direccion ip.html"><img src="imagenes/11.jpg" width="150" alt="direccion ip dns etcetera" title="obtener dirección ip, gateway, dns, mascara de subred"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/vista windows.html"><img src="imagenes/12.jpg" width="150" alt="cambio de accdidenta de aplicaciones de windows 8" title="cambio de accdidenta de aplicaciones de windows 8"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/captura de pantalla.html"><img src="imagenes/13.jpg" width="150" alt="atajo para capturar pantalla sin paint" title="atajo para capturar pantalla sin paint"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/cookies chrome.html"><img src="imagenes/14.jpg" width="150" alt="desactivar cookies en chrome" title="desactivar cookies en chrome"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/configmicrofono.html"><img src="imagenes/15.jpg" width="150" alt="configurar microfono" title="configurar microfono"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/ocultar video.html"><img src="imagenes/16.jpg" width="150" alt="ocultar información de video" title="Tapar información de video"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/cortar video.html"><img src="imagenes/17.jpg" width="150" alt="cortar video de youtube" title="cortar video de youtube"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/guardar sesión chrome.html"><img src="imagenes/18.jpg" width="150" alt="guardar sesión e chrome rápidamente" title="guarda sesión en chrome rápidamente"></a>

        <a href="paginas principales/convertir ventana a pestaña.html"><img src="imagenes/5.jpg" width="150" alt="convertir ventana a pestaña y vicecersa" title="convertir ventana a pestaña y vicecersa"></a></p>
    </article>
  </section>
  
  </section>
  <footer><p>Portoviejo-Manabí-Ecuador</p></footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: esa clase tal vez ya cuenta aquí section.modal{
 background-color: #111;
 box-shadow: 0% 0% 10% #000;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 5% auto;
 padding: 5%;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%; sino dime en que parte de mi código html podría añadir la sección

Comment: <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal3" class="open"> CONTACTO</a>
      <section id="openmodal3" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal-ancho">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> CONTACTO</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Comunicate con nosotros a este correo susanaloorgarcia@gmail.com</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div> </li>

Comment: Si yo vi que ya tenías esa clase y aún así, te sugiero usar otra. Si quieres que eso mismo se aplique a todas los modales, puedes hacerlo ahí sin problema. Ahora yo te recomiendo usarlo independiente, de hecho al principio del css, lo pongo para que veas como es. Y en el html, se lo agrego solo al modal.

Comment: no tengo un telefono movil porque me lo robaron pero conseguí que se viera el scroll, cualquier otra cosa te vuelvo a molestar

Comment: Un placer, por cierto puedes usar el inspector de elementos como emulador de celulares, solo debes presionar `F12` y cuando aparezca la consola, presiona al tiempo `ctrl + shift + M`. Éxitos!

Comment: amigo tengo una pregunta porque repetistes el modal es decir pusistes modal modal-ancho?

Comment: Para re-usar la clase que ya definiste en modal, es una "técnica" conocida como **multiclase**, de esa forma puedes extender funcionalidades a una clase ya definida sin que se afecten las demás y poder seguir usandola en otras sin necesidad de que otras clases se afecten, aparte repites menos código. Una forma de uso muy conocida es para colores de fondo, por ejemplo: `div class="caja azul"` y `div class="caja roja"`, pueden compartir en la clase `caja`, el ancho y el alto, entre otras y con la segunda clase definimos el color.

Comment: **Un ejemplo de lo que te digo:** [Multiclases](https://codepen.io/g3kdigital/pen/eVYjxp). Como ves sigo conservando el estilo de las cajas dispuestas en horizontal y con el mismo tamaño definido en la clase **caja**, aplico el cambio de color, añadiendo una clase de color que puedo reusar cuando quiera y cada vez que necesite que alguna caja sea más **angosta** o más **ancha** uso esas clases además de la clase **caja**.